# How to trim database column in SQL comparison for Rails 3.2.12?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

Please look at the following example:

```
UserAccess.where("action = ? AND resource = ? ", 'index', 'logs')
```

The issue we are facing is that there are white space in column action and resource in database table. In order to make this comparison work, we have to trim action and resource first. We tried function trim() and it seems it's not working.

Is there a way we can trim the columns before putting them in comparison in Rails SQL? Ideally the solution is not db engine specific, even though we are using sqlite3.

Comment: Are you saying `UserAccess.where("TRIM(action) = ? AND TRIM(resource) = ? ", 'index', 'logs')` does not work?

Comment: Yes. just used low case trim. does low case matter?

Comment: No, case should not matter. But trim() should work. Note also that things would be cleaner if you stripped whitespaces before inserting into the UserAccess table.

Comment: You are right. But we have no control over the data entered. If you put the above as a formal reply, will mark it as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`trim()` should work, and is case insensitive:

```
UserAccess.where("TRIM(action) = ? AND TRIM(resource) = ? ", 'index', 'logs')
```

Note also that things would be cleaner if you stripped whitespaces before inserting into the UserAccess table.